# Set config's 'browsers' property in the command line in karma runner

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I usually use *browsers=['PhantomJS']* for running my specs with karma because it's faster than chrome and I find a bit annoying when chrome opens the browser in front of the window on every boot.

But when I have a bug and I need to debug, I change karma.conf.js browsers to ['Chrome'].

I would like to set this property when I start karma, something like: **'karma start --browsers=[Chrome]'**.

Is this posible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you just have to use the --browsers parameter and it'll overide your config file browsers part.

```sh
$ karma start config/testacular.conf.js --browsers Chrome
```

where Chrome is the name of the browser or a path to a binary.

For example, I have only a small Qt browser configured. if I use the line above, it runs Chrome instead.

```sh
INFO [karma]: Karma server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 24.0 (Linux)]: Connected on socket id DxbVJNX0jIoe1CbaWf9V
Chrome 24.0 (Linux): Executed 74 of 74 SUCCESS (0.443 secs / 0.232 secs)
...
```

or, for example, I have firefox beta, aurora and release in my home. I run beta with:

```sh
$ karma start config/testacular.conf.js --browsers ~/firefox/firefox
```

```sh
$ karma start --help
Karma - Spectacular Test Runner for JavaScript.

START - Start the server / do a single run.

Usage:
  karma start [<configFile>] [<options>]

Options:
  --port                <integer> Port where the web server is running.                        
  --runner-port         <integer> Port where the server is listening for runner.               
  --auto-watch          Auto watch source files and run on change.                             
  --no-auto-watch       Do not watch source files.                                             
  --log-level           <disable | error | warn | info | debug> Level of logging.              
  --colors              Use colors when reporting and printing logs.                           
  --no-colors           Do not use colors when reporting or printing logs.                     
  --reporters           List of reporters (available: dots, progress, junit).                  
  --browsers            List of browsers to start (eg. --browsers Chrome,ChromeCanary,Firefox).
  --capture-timeout     <integer> Kill browser if does not capture in given time [ms].         
  --single-run          Run the test when browsers captured and exit.                          
  --no-single-run       Disable single-run.                                                    
  --report-slower-than  <integer> Report tests that are slower than given time [ms].           
  --help                Print usage and options.                                               
  --version             Print current version.
```